# What's wrong with my Prolog "list filler"?

Tags: prolog

I wrote a simple program to try and populate a list of a given length with elements that meet a certain constraint.

For example, I want to create a list of 4 integers between 0 and 9, which at least contains `3` and `4`. I can think of several (thousands, really) such lists:

```
[3,4,0,0]
[0,3,4,0]
[3,1,9,4]
etc...
```

But SWI Prolog just returns `false`. Am I just making some kind of logical mistake, or am I using Prolog wrong?

My code:

```
is_single_digit_integer(N) :-
  integer(N),
  between(0, 9, N).

filled_list(Given, FillConstraint, OutLen, Out) :-
  is_list(Out),
  length(Out, OutLen),
  length(Given, GivenLen),
  between(0, OutLen, GivenLen),
  maplist(FillConstraint, Out),
  subset(Given, Out).
```

And running the example I described:

```
?- filled_list([3,4], is_single_digit_integer, 4, X).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `integer(N)` and `is_list(Out)` assume bound variables and fail on uninstantiated variables. The solution is to remove them:

```
is_single_digit_integer(N) :-
  between(0, 9, N).

filled_list(Given, FillConstraint, OutLen, Out) :-
  length(Out, OutLen),
  length(Given, GivenLen),
  between(0, OutLen, GivenLen),
  maplist(FillConstraint, Out),
  subset(Given, Out).
```

You can see it works now:

```
?- filled_list([3,4], is_single_digit_integer, 4, X).
X = [0, 0, 3, 4] ;
X = [0, 0, 4, 3] ;
X = [0, 1, 3, 4] ;
X = [0, 1, 4, 3] .
```

I think you're trying to use these predicates as if they are type constraints, but Prolog just doesn't work like that. Trust in your types a bit and everything will be fine; after all, `between` isn't going to give you anything but integers and `length` isn't going to give you anything but lists.

Bonus trick:

```
?- filled_list([3,4], between(0,9), 4, X).
X = [0, 0, 3, 4] ;
X = [0, 0, 4, 3] ;
X = [0, 1, 3, 4] ;
X = [0, 1, 4, 3] ;
X = [0, 2, 3, 4] .
```

Comment: Good to know about `length` and `between`. I was indeed trying to impose type constraints. How can I tell whether a predicate assumes its input is bound? Just the "+ParamName" in documentation, or something more fundamental?

Comment: @ssdecontrol Documentation, unfortunately, is the only real way. (If having a REPL isn't high on your priority list, you might enjoy programming in [Mercury](https://www.mercurylang.org/), which combines a Haskell-like type system with a stronger model of declarative programming than Prolog, but keeps most of Prolog's syntax).

Comment: @ssdecontrol: I think this would be well worth a separate question!

Answer (score 5):

I would like to complement Daniel's answer with a short pointer to [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity):

The *via regia* to general Prolog programs is to use predicates that satisfy properties you expect from logical relations. Such predicates are called **pure** and **monotonic**.

For example, in your particular case, you are using the *non-monotonic* predicates `integer/1` and `is_list/1`. Your issue goes away completely if you *instead* use predicates that can be used in *all directions*, such as:

```
is_single_digit_integer(N) :-
  N in 0..9.
```

This uses the [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) constraint `(in)/2` to state: `N` is an *integer* between 0 and 9.

It works in all of the following cases:

```
?- is_single_digit_integer(N).
N in 0..9.

?- is_single_digit_integer(3).
true.

?- is_single_digit_integer(20).
false.
```

In contrast, `integer/1` is *incomplete*:

```
?- integer(N).
false.
```

→ No integer exists??

The same holds for `is_list/1`, which falls critically short already for the *most general* query:

```
?- is_list(Ls).
false.
```

In contrast, to state that `Ls` is a list, you can for example use:

```
length(Ls, _)
```

This works correctly *whether or not* `Ls` is instantiated. For example:

```
?- length(Ls, _).
Ls = [] ;
Ls = [_6650] ;
Ls = [_6650, _6656] ;
Ls = [_6650, _6656, _6662] ;
etc.
```

To get the most out of Prolog, I recommend to stay in its pure and monotonic subset. This paves the way for relations that can be used in all directions.